# three.js dynamic fragment shader GUI

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

Im using the three.js webGL shader example, and I'm trying to add a GUI to control the parameters of the shader dynamically in real time. is this possible? it seems that when I try to add the effectController variable outside of the shader scripts it seems to work fine but when I try to make a dynamic GUI variable for in the shader scripts I get "shader could not compile" console errors.

three.js:16617 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  ERROR: 0:109: 'effectController' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:109: 'horzMod' :  field selection requires structure or vector on left hand side

```
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    void main() {
        e=(effectController.horzMod);
    }

</script>

<script>
    var effectController = {
        horzMod: 400
    };
    function initGUI() {
         var gui = new dat.GUI();

         gui.add( effectController, "horzMod", 1, 400, 1 );
    }
    function init() {
        console.log(effectController.horizontalSpace)
        initGUI();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean like [THIS](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/matrix.html) ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. But it is not as easy as just using JS-variables within the shader: The shader isn't even Javascript. The language shaders are written in is called GLSL, and you should first take a few hours to read up on that, I find [this piece on html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/shaders/) quite helpful (and if you want to dive a bit deeper, here's a [WebGL fundamentals article about GLSL](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shaders-and-glsl.html)).

Now that you read that, you will understand that you need to pass the values for your parameters into the shaders as uniforms, like for instance `uniform float horzMod;`.

In THREE.js you will need to know about how to use the shader-material, which has [the relevant documentation here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/ShaderMaterial). You will end up with something like this:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: '...',
  fragmentShader: '...',
  uniforms: {
    horzMod: { value: 400 }
  }
});
```

And now you are at the point where you could add a gui-element to the uniform-value. Using [dat.GUI](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage), this is pretty easy:

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(material.uniforms.horzMod, 'value', 0, 1000)
    .name('horzMod');
```